# Table with db information

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I want to create a '`master`' db which should only have one table.
In this table are the fields:

```
|DBname|DBowner|Task|created|updated|
```

The information about `DBname`, `DBowner` and the created field should be automaticly filled (these information could be used from the DB settings).

I want that table for history and for an overview. I also searched for something similar but didn't found anything. Could someone can get me some hinds for that?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is this MySQL or SQL Server? If SQL Server, then I recommend looking into DDL triggers. Here's an instance level trigger to get you started: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Alert-for-new-database-f740068a

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, you can try using the built in schema table, such as this:
    select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATE_TIME,UPDATE_TIME from information_schema.tables

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the table information as well as DB information from following query :**

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_catalog = 'DB_name' AND table_name = 'Table_name'
```